# Running another target after existing one

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Imagine we have an existing (untouchable) Makefile with target "foo", and another included Makefile which I can modify. I would like to add a new target called "runafter" which shall be executed after "foo" was run. So the user keeps calling "foo" and some additional code shall be run afterwards.

The usual way to achieve this would be to rename the original ones and do something like:

```
foo_old:
  ...
foo: foo_old
  # run some code or call another target explicitly
  $(MAKE) runafter
```

But that only works if you can rename `foo`. If not, how could I extend the behavior of the existing target? Everything I tried to do with `foo: ...` apparently causes overriding of the old foo target (with warning). But I just want to run some code afterwards!

Comment: What about `runafter: foo bar`?

Comment: Not good, misses the point. User shall still call "foo" target and not "runafter" or some other target.

Comment: So please edit your question and explain that.

Comment: Explain what exactly? That the user keeps calling the old targets? I though this is obvious, but if you like that more explicitly, sure.

Comment: There is no way to do this generally, if you can't modify the original makefile.  Your only option is to locate some variable that is used in the recipe of the `foo` target, and modify it in your included file in such a way that it performs its original task, plus invokes a sub-make at the end that runs whatever extra stuff you want.

Comment: BTW I agree with Renaud it was not at all obvious originally that you couldn't ask the user to run a different target instead.  I guess that's another option: you could provide a shell script wrapper for `make` that modified the targets that the user would run before invoking make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see how to do this from the included makefile but if you use GNU make then you can add a makefile named `makefile` instead of `Makefile`:

```sh
$ cat makefile
foo:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile $@
    $(MAKE) runafter

runafter:
    ...
```

From the GNU make man page:

> If no  -f  option  is  present, make will look for the makefiles `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order.

So you can also name it `GNUmakefile` if you wish. With one or the other running `make foo` should do what you want.